# 2nd monitor not detected

Tags: windows-7, display

I'm having problems adding a second monitor to my computer. Computer is a Dell Optiplex 780 running W7(64). The computer has a VGA port and a DisplayPort. Main monitor is connected via DisplayPort to VGI connector. 
I tried adding a second monitor using the VGA port and hoping that plug/play would work, but W7 cannot detect the second monitor (I used the "Detect" function in display settings). I then tried to reboot. However, the reboot is interrupted with a message on the second monitor (VGA) saying the the computer is setup to use the DisplayPort. At that point I need to disconnect the second monitor and reboot to use the first monitor. 
Any thoughts on how to get this configuration to work?
Thanks.

Comment: The [technical guidebook](http://i.dell.com/sites/content/business/solutions/engineering-docs/en/Documents/optiplex-780-tech-guide.pdf) says "The DisplayPort controller does not support multi-monitor display" (page 23). Not sure if that relates to your situation though.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround is to boot on DP, and then connect the VGA display. It's tedious but it gets the job done.

Comment: Not an answer. You will be able to add comments to others posts when you have more reputation.